# Non blocking render in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS and trying to build some application on it.

When I'm trying to modify my state and render, my page is freezing and can't do anything until the render is finished when my components become huge.

I found that I can use `shouldComponentUpdate` to optimize my code, but the question comes to me is: Can I make this render procedure be non blocking? And so I can tell the user that the page is processing some heavy loading executions and please wait or maybe show the progress of the execution? Or if the user can cancel the render, for example, for a live editor, if user edit the content of the editor, the "preview" section will stop rendering old content and trying to render new content without blocking the editor UI?

Here's the heavy loading example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      var Box = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
          return (
            <div>Box</div>
          );
        }
      });
      
      var CommentBox = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
          return {box_count: 5};
        },
        
        heavyLoadRender: function() {
          this.setState({box_count: 40000});
        },
        
        render: function() {
          var render_box = [];
          for (var i=0; i<this.state.box_count; i++) {
            render_box.push(<Box />);
          }
          return (
            <div>
              {render_box}
              <button onClick={this.heavyLoadRender}>Start</button>
            </div>
          );
        }
      });
      
      ReactDOM.render(
        <CommentBox />,
        document.getElementById('content')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I press `Start`, the page will freeze and no response until all `Box` is rendered. Is it possible to add a button named `Cancel` which user can cancel the render and clear all boxes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a great question, and a perfect use case for `setTimeout` which can schedule an update to the next round of the event loop.

Rather than store the number of components to render, store an array of components, and render them directly. **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/39189/)**

```
 var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return { boxes: [<Box key="first" />] };
    },

    heavyLoadRender: function() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.state.boxes.length < 50000) {
          this.setState({ 
            boxes: this.state.boxes.concat(<Box key={this.state.boxes.length} />)
          })
          this.heavyLoadRender()
        }
      })
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.heavyLoadRender}>Start</button>
          {this.state.boxes}
        </div>
      )
    }
  })
```

Update:

<s>If you only want to show the state once the array is filled up, don't display anything until it hits that size:</s>

This did not work:

```
{ this.state.boxes.length === 50000 && this.state.boxes }
```

Hope is not lost though! Use style!

```
<div style={{ display: this.state.boxes.length === 50000 ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
  { this.state.boxes }
</div>
```

If you want to increase the speed, you can push more than item per `setTimeout`

```
var newBoxes = []
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   newBoxes.push(<Box />)
}
this.setState({ 
  boxes: this.state.boxes.concat(newBoxes)
})
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1Lpa6v9/1/). I think this whole class of problems is going to take time to perform. In batches of 10,000 the basic box component doesn't block and you could easily throw a loading spinner up there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This answer works great (not blocking the UI) with the example I provided, but there are several problems. First, this method take too long to complete compares to the original method. Second, if the Box is a huge component, for example, if  it is a `BigBox` which contains 200 `Box` inside, then this method still make UI delayed. Finally, this method generate boxes in each state, which shows the intermediate result to the user. What if I want user to see the final result instead of temporary result?

Comment: Your last point is simple, `{ this.state.boxes.length === max && this.state.boxes }`.. and if your `Box` component takes a long time to render you might need to fill its boxes up in a non-blocking way as well.

Comment: And you can speed render rate by batching concats. Updated answer

Comment: I tried `{ this.state.boxes.length === 50000 && this.state.boxes }` and it shows only all boxed added to the array, but when it starts to render all boxes, my browser is freezing, just like the original problem. And I thought I can append more than 1 box per `setTimeout`, too, but it suffered from the UI delayed problem as I mentioned in previous comment (I tried with 200 boxes per setTimeout, and that's why I mentioned BigBox with 200 Box in it).

Comment: updated my answer again. Getting the right number of batches will be the trick here.

Comment: I think there are a number of different optimization techniques that could be used here but it would depend on things specific to your application.

Comment: After doing some more research, I found this may be the correct answer at the current stage of the Javascript. Currently Javascript only can do multithreading with the limitation that background thread cannot modify the DOM. The example I provided is not practical because it wastes so many time on DOM manipulation. In most cases this won't happen, and logical part can do separately with Web Workers. Using setTimeout is another great solution, too. I think it's the limitation of the Javascript now, we have to find our own way to optimize it.

Comment: I'm wondering if React can provide an option to make `render` uses Web Workers to do the logical part of the execution. For example, they can use Web Workers to do Virtual DOM comparison in background instead of freezing the current thread.