# Loop through array async

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, reactjs

I have this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { arr } from '../../../modules/ranks';
import { LOVE } from '../../components/svg/LOVE';

export const map = () => {
  let col = 9;
  let j = 9;
  let k = 9;

  return (
    arr.map((rank, i) => {
      if (i === col) {
        col = col + j--;
        if (j === 0) {
          j = k--;
        }
        return [
          <LOVE key={ rank } rank={ rank } />,
          <div className="clearfix"></div>,
        ];
      }
      return (
        <LOVE key={ rank } rank={ rank } />
      );
    })
  );
};
```

Basically, I have a array of ranks (modules/ranks) that just a long list. But I need to add clearfix div on some of them as I map through to look presentable on the website.

What I have above works, but the array is long and will get longer so the page has to wait until it finishes looping before it displays the rest of the website.

I've been looking at async, and I tried to make it work but honestly its too hard for me to grasp...

Can someone help me use caolan/async? I read the docs many times...

Separate question for azium:
@azium
Thanks for referring me to your post. I tried to get it to work but I'm not sure.. it's not loading anything at the moment. The parent component is a simple render `<map />`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { arr } from '../../../modules/ranks';
import { LOVE } from '../../components/svg/LOVE';

export class map extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      LOVE: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.load();
  }

  load() {
    let col = 9;
    let j = 9;
    let k = 9;
    setTimeout(() => {
      arr.map((rank, i) => {
        if (i === col) {
          col = col + j--;
          if (j === 0) {
            j = k--;
          }
          return (
            this.setState({
              LOVE: this.state.LOVE.concat([
                <LOVE key={ rank } rank={ rank } />,
                <div className="clearfix"></div>,
              ]),
            })
          );
        }
        return (
          this.setState({
            LOVE: this.state.LOVE.concat(<LOVE key={ rank } rank={ rank } />),
          })
        );
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.LOVE }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `setTimeout` ?

Comment: Yeah, you could have a setTimeout in your component that eventually resolves setting the state with the results, which would cause the render cycle for the component to kick in and then you can display the results via the state.  When you say the list is long, just how much data are you talking about? I'll put this in an answer for you.

Comment: react always renders synchronously.

Comment: I never heard of setTimeout, I'll go read about that now. The current list is 220, the max it will become is 1500. It's just a simple array of strings though.

Comment: I answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708734/non-blocking-render-in-reactjs/36709326#36709326

Comment: @azium thanks for that post, I looked over it and tried to use it but couldn't get it to work. I updated my question above with the non-working code.. Could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what I was describing within my comment on your post.  I have created a component that imports your `map` and then executes asynchronously via `setTimeout` and subsequently calls the `this.setState` for the component.

```
import React from 'react';
import map from './map';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { loveElements: [] };
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     // async
     setTimeout(() => {
       const loveElements = map();
       this.setState({ loveElements: loveElements });
     }, 0);
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <div>
          {this.state.loveElements}
       </div>
     );
   }
}
```

Comment: Well this wouldn't work because the call to `map` is what is taking the time. You would need to replace `arr.map` in the original function to use `setTimeout` instead of the loop so each iteration of the array is done asynchronously.

Comment: Nice, now it's loading the layout first before the array... so let me know if I got this correctly. When the component loads, it sets initial state of loveElement to empty array, and then renders it. Once componentDidMount, it runs the map of loveElements and set the state right?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I see your point.  If OP is wanting partial results to be display this isn't the way to go.

Comment: @cocacrave - yeah, it renders the component and then fires a "thread" to run the `map` and get the elements. Once they are done the state gets set and your component re-renders with the results.

Comment: @cocacrave - azium is suggesting we could make some improvements to the `map` function which will allow you to render partial results as they are getting processed, but that is more complicated.  You have quite a small dataset so try this first and see.

Comment: Actually, I posted above, it works correctly and now the layout appears and a second later the array is mapped out. I can leave it as is but I am curious and want to learn about loading partial results 'as they get processed'. It's not even necessary for me but could you show me that as well?

Comment: @cocacrave I left a comment in your question where I implement such a scheme. It's not that complicated really.

Comment: @ctrlplusb in your example code you can drop setTimeout and get the same result because `componentDidMount` will happen after the initial view is rendered already

Answer (score -1):

Looks like [lazy.js](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/) might be of use to you...

```
var asyncSequence = Lazy(array)
  .async(100) // specifies a 100-millisecond interval between each element
  .map(inc)
  .filter(isEven)
  .take(20);

// This function returns immediately and begins iterating over the sequence asynchronously.
asyncSequence.each(function(e) {
  console.log(new Date().getMilliseconds() + ": " + e);
});

function inc(x) { return x + 1; }
function isEven(x) { return x % 2 === 0; }
```